# Check if SSH is enabled or Disabled in Solaris 11

Tags: ssh, solaris

**How can I check to see if SSH is enabled on Solaris 11?** I have tried typing `ssh` in the terminal, and it came back with a list of options, which none of them made sense to me.

All I want to know is if it is enabled or not.

I am trying to use `PuTTY` to connect remotely, so I know my IP address that I'm connecting to is correct, but I'm not sure if SSH is enabled on this system.

The reason I tried just typing `ssh`, was because I normally test to see if `gcc` is enabled, by typing `gcc` in the terminal. So I thought it would be the same concept.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: My PuTTY wasn't using the correct IP address as I thought it was. I had to change it, as my Network Admin told me to change my IP addresses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`svcs ssh` will tell you if the ssh service is enabled (online) on your Solaris 11 machine or not.

Note that gcc isn't a service but a command. Running `ssh` alone and having it displaying possible options means the ssh command (i.e. client) is available.

Comment: What about on SPARC, as when I tried `svcs ssh`, it said `svcs: not found`. **Is it different for SPARC?**

Comment: Not at all, svc is part of smf http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/overview/servicemgmthowto-jsp-135655.html#0 introduced in Solaris 10 in 2005. Solaris is the same OS regardless of the hardware architecture. I guess your SPARC box is just using Solaris 9 or older.

Comment: Hi @jlliagre, I did `uname -a` and this returned: `SunOS -I 5.8 Generic_108528-29 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-100`. What version of Solaris is that?

Comment: That's the aging Solaris 8. `cat /etc/release` shows the precise version/update.

Comment: Ah: `Solaris 8 2/02 s28s_u7wos_08a SPARC` - OK, thank you for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Memory is that Solaris 8 didn't have a built-in ssh server.  I think we had to download and compile a SSH server.  OpenSSH?

You can check your latest Solaris 8 media to see if there is a pkg included in one of the later updates as a base or extra package.

Also, on the server side, sshd is the daemon, ssh is the client.  And look to see if any pkgs are installed that might give you ssh:
 `pkginfo |grep -i ssh`